# How to get OUTPUT $action, Inserted.*,Deleted.* records in In SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, ssis

I was just wondering, in `MERGE` in T-SQL, you can output the `OUTPUT $action`, `Inserted.*` and `Deleted.*` records. I want to ask how can I get `OUTPUT $action`, `Inserted.*`, `Deleted.*` records in SSIS?

Comment: Before you invest too much in `MERGE`, [please read this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). IMHO you're better off keeping your inserts, updates and deletes separate.

Comment: OUTPUT will work on INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE also.  In order to answer your question though we will probably need more detail as to what you are trying to do.  Maybe an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, ish, is the short answer.

You have 3 ish components in a data flow task that can modify data. OLE DB/ADO.NET Destination, OLE DB Command and a Script Component.

I'm ignoring Script Component for this answer as it's the swiss army knife of components. If you want to do something badly enough, the Script Component will allow you to. Whether cutting down a sequoia tree with the miniature saw is realistic is another matter.

OLE DB Destination is that, a destination. It doesn't push rows out, it only consumes them. Yes, technically it can push rows but that's only through the error output path which still won't solve the problem of getting access to the OUTPUT virtual tables.

OLE DB Command sounds promising. It can add additional columns to your data flow. The big, BIG, **BIG**, downside is that it is not a set based component. It's going to operate on each individual row that flows through. If there's tens, hundreds, maybe thousands of rows, this singleton behaviour probably isn't going to kill your systems. `MERGE`ing lakhs+ of data is probably going to result in you having a bad time.

If you're deadset on this approach, recognizing the failings with [MERGE](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/), the way to make it SSISey, would be to have two data flow components.

The first writes all of your data to a destination table. Take your existing DF and write all the data to a new table.

The second, new Data Flow, uses your MERGE statement with the accompanying virtual tables directed as needed. I talked about a [delete first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503959/ssis-foreach-through-a-table-insert-into-another-and-delete-the-source-row/15508174#15508174) pattern which used the OUTPUT table over on that SO question so the MERGE shouldn't be any different.

Comment: What about using a multicast?  That way the OP can send one copy of the data to one destination and another to the "output".  That would give them the equivalent of the "inserted" information anyway.  Not sure how they would get the "deleted" though.

Comment: @KennethFisher The challenge with that, even for the inserted virtual, is if they wanted to associate `Source business key` 10 maps to  `Target surrogate key` 8213. The 8213 value wouldn't be present in the Multicast. Good theory, just can't figure out how to make it "work" but if I'm missing something, please post as an answer

Answer (score 2):

From SQL 2012 onwards, there is the [WITH RESULT SETS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EXEC_TSQL);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) option, which makes it easy to use the output from the OUTPUT clause with no sticky issues in SSIS not understanding the metadata for the resultset, eg you can use the output from an OUTPUT clause in SSIS Source components, eg OLE DB Source.

I set up a simple example using a stored procedure with MERGE and an OUTPUT clause capturing the action.  The OLE DB Source component calls the stored proc, the MERGE runs and the OUTPUT is delivered as a resultset from the proc.  It can be then be joined to a destination, eg OLE DB Destination or other Data Flow transform.

[image]

As to whether or not you should do this, is a different question.  You would probably be better off using another proc to consume the output, unless of course there was a specific reason you needed the output in the Data Flow pipeline.  SSIS real power is more for moving data between different servers, custom .net tasks and running tasks in parallel.